# Prove $\sum \frac{\cos nz}{n!}$ converges on compact sets

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, entire-functions

Prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \displaystyle\frac{\cos nz}{n!}$$

Is an entire function, which means that it uniformly convergent on compact sets

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $z\in\mathbb{R}$, your series is the real part of
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{e^{inz}}{n!} = e^{e^{iz}} = e^{\cos(z)}\left(\cos(\sin z)+i\sin(\sin z)\right),$$
so:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\cos(nz)}{n!} = e^{\cos(z)}\cos(\sin(z)) $$
holds for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ by analytic continuation (or simply by writing $\cos(nz)$ as $\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$), and the RHS is an entire function, since the product or composition of two entire functions is still an entire function. At last, if we have an entire function, its Taylor series (centered at any $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$) is uniformly convergent to the function over any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Here $\|z\|\leq R$ grants 
$$ \|\cos(nz)\|\leq 2 e^{nR} $$
and 
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{ 2 e^{nR}}{n!} = 2 e^{e^R} < +\infty. $$

Comment: But z is a complex number. Thus, cos(sin z) and sin(sin z) are might not be real. And, it is not true that $\sum a_n+b_n$ converges implies $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: @WorawitTepsan: we are dealing with holomorphic functions, that is no wonder that $\cos(z)$ may not be real, but $\cos(z)$ is an entire function, and the Taylor series of an entire function converges to the function over any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to understand the proof.

Comment: Anyway, I refined my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch:

You can use that $\cos(nx + n iy) = \cos nx \cosh ny - i\sin nx \sinh ny$ to obtain that  $|\cos nz| \leq e^{|ny|}$. Since factorials grow faster than exponentials, the complex version of the Weierstrass $M$-test will imply the result.